# android studio project upgrade kotlin_version version

Tags: android, build.gradle, dagger-hilt

My current android project kotlin_version = '1.5.32'

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
        hilt_version = '2.40.5'
        nav_version = '2.3.5'
    }
```

Trying to upgrade it to 1.7.20 or 1.6.0, I am getting the following build error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptQADebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I think it probably has something to do wiht hilt and/or navigation component, do you think so?  any tips how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

look this doc:

```
https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=zh_cn
```

upgrade kotlin_version version,must to check JDK、android build plugin、gradle、android studio version